# Referencing namespaces in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-namespaces

Need to get an XSD definition that can generate output like this. I'm having trouble referencing namespaces. I want to do it all in one XSD file (do not want to reference other files).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<message>
  <Headerinfo>
    <Element1>stuff</Element1>
    <Element2>things</Element2>
  </Headerinfo>
  <CreateRequest xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyOrg.MyApp.DataContracts.MyObject" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Element3>more stuff</Element3>
    <Element4>more things</Element4>
    <Address xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyOrg.MyApp.DataContracts.Address">
      <a:AddressLine1>123 Main Street</a:AddressLine1>
    </Address>
  </CreateRequest>
</message>
```

1 - Need to be able to generate the xmlns for the CreateRequest complex element.
2 - Need to be able to generate the xmlns:a for Address and its simple elements.

Here is the XSD I have so far. I believe I need to add an xs:scehma entry for the a: record. Not sure what else, can't seem to get it working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="message">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Headerinfo">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Element1" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="Element2" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="CreateRequest">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Element3" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="Element4" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="Address">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <a:element name="AddressLine1" type="xs:string"/>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to achieve this without referencing another XSD file, since the root has no namespace, and some content uses namespaces. In fact, you need exactly three XSD files.

In general, the other way around might be possible, by setting the form to unqualified for elements without a namespace.

Comment: My research is leading me to this as well. I tried playing around with the unqualified setting, but I'm not sure what else I would add to the mix to capitalize on that.

Comment: @atalien, unfortunately, there's nothing else... if your message is qualified, and the other elements unqualified, then you could do it in one XSD. If you end up referencing an element/attribute in any other namespace, then no way you can achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by XSD "generating output" - XSD is usually used for validating input.

But the XML Schema spec requires you to write one schema document per namespace, with each document containing xs:import declarations to define the dependencies across namespaces. That's the way it's designed and there's no point trying to fight it.